# Problem with getting specific data based on several factors in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system where a user is part of a series of "runs", to each "run", can be added courses, teachers(users), classes and so on.

Each teacher(user) has chosen his/her classes & courses.
Here's a run-down of the tables I have that are relevant:

```
lam_run - The run in it self.
lam_run_course - Relational table that shows what runs has what courses
lam_teacher_course - Relational table that shows which teacher has which courses
lam_run_teacher - Relational table that shows what teachers are in what courses
```

What I want to do is show each teacher which runs that are relevant to them (based on which courses they have selected seen in lam_teacher_course) but in which they are not already participating.

Here's the MySQL code I have so far that does not work:

```
$query_relevant_runs = "
SELECT DISTINCT 
    lam_run_course.run_id
FROM 
    lam_teacher_course, 
    lam_run_course, 
    lam_run, lam_run_teacher
WHERE 
    lam_teacher_course.user_id = '1' 
AND 
    lam_teacher_course.course_id = lam_run_course.course_id 
AND 
    lam_run_teacher.user_id != '1'";
```

Instead this code shows all runs that are relevant, but it doesn't exclude the runs the user is already in..

What can I do to fix this?

Ps. Sorry for bad title, no idea what I should've called it :S

Here is a link to part of the databases (the relevant part): [Link!](http://pastebin.com/gP0e5vaW)

Comment: I cannot help to think that there is something wrong with the JOIN...
"lam_teacher_course.course_id = lam_run_course.course_id" 
but since we don't have the table is really hard to say what it is ..

Comment: Would it help if I added a db dump from phpmyadmin of the relevant tables? :)

Comment: Give it a shot - at least we can try do debug it. It looks like the query is good though ... I don't see any syntax errors, so it's gotta be the logic.

Comment: I have added it to the main post, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
LEFT JOIN `lam_run_teacher` `lam_run_teach_exclude`
ON `lam_run_teacher_exclude`.`user_id` = `lam_teacher_user`.`user_id`
...
WHERE `lam_run_teacher`.`user_id` IS NULL
```

The LEFT JOIN takes your current query, and appends the additional data to it. However, unlike the INNER JOIN you are using now (using the kinda-strange multiple-from syntax), the LEFT JOIN does not limit your resultset to just those where there is data for the righthand side. The righthand columns will be NULL. By filtering on that NULL, you can find all runs that are interesting, and for which there is not yet a relation to the teacher.

Does this help?

I'd recommend always using the normal join syntax (`INNER JOIN target on target.id = source.id`) - that way you're more aware of the idea that there are other kinds of join as well, and all your joins will look identical. It takes some getting used to, but definitely helps when your queries get more complex.

Also, in your cross-referencing tables, you can drop the primary key columns. If the only purpose of a table is to define a link between two tables, make the primary key consist of the two keys you've got. Unless you want to be able to related the same teacher to a run multiple times...

---

OK, took me way longer than it should have, but here's the complete thing:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT `lam_run_course`.run_id
FROM
    `lam_run_course`
INNER JOIN
    `lam_teacher_course` 
    ON `lam_teacher_course`.course_id = `lam_teacher_course`.course_id
LEFT JOIN
    `lam_run_teacher` ON (`lam_run_teacher`.`run_id` = `lam_run_course`.`run_id` AND `lam_run_teacher`.`user_id` = 3)
WHERE
    `lam_teacher_course`.user_id = 3
    and `lam_run_teacher`.`run_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Actually no, I don't really understand that:S It doesn't seem like it takes my current query? And what is lam_run_teach_exclude?

Comment: Hi Eax - sorry about that. lam_run_teacher_exclude is an alias. Because we'll be joining against the table twice, you need to alias one of the two joins, or MySQL won't know for which table this condition is valid. I'll update my answer to include your whole query instead of just the snippets to insert, give me a few moments :)

Comment: Thanks! :) I learn A LOT better by example than getting an explanation :)

Comment: Hmm, it returns the correct runs (I think), but I had to remove the "and `lam_run_teacher`.`run_id` IS NULL", because it only returned data where the run_id was NULL (I need the run_id :)), also, it seems to return the runs several times? And adding DISTINCT doesn't work :/ What can I do? :)

Comment: Hi Eax: Perhaps I don't understand what information you're trying to query... but could it be you're looking for wrong run_id? ;) There is one in lam_run_course, which means "this run ID is part of a course in which this teacher is registered". The run ID at the end of the resultset is "this teacher is already registered in this run" , so I think you really should have the null option. I've altered the query to do a distinct.